# Android phone powers on spontaneously during charging

Tags: charging, power-on

I want to charge the phone while it's powered OFF.

But it automatically turns itself ON during charging.  It may be 87% or 90% or 100%.  I don't know the exact reason.

Model = LG-K430n.

I don't like cell phone radiation and I rarely use the phone at all.  I just want it to be OFF most of the time.  This is driving me nuts.

Comment: There are devices that are designed to power on when connected to a charger. If you don't want your phone to emit radio signals use the Airplane mode.

Answer (score 0):

It's by OEM design. See [support questions](https://www.lg.com/hk_en/support/product/lg-LGK430N.AHKGKU) and in particular this one [My phone automatically turns on when I connect the charger. Why?](https://www.lg.com/hk_en/support/product-help/CT20136018-1439979129988) which says

> Your smartphone will turn on automatically when the charger is connected. Please be assured that it is a sign of normal operation.

And to prevent it from turning on

> To charge when your smartphone is off, connect the charger first and press the Power button to turn off your phone. The display will not be turned on.
> When the remaining battery is less than 5%, the battery temperature is too high or low, or the smartphone is turned off due to the high temperature, the screen will not turn on.